# How to run a directory located inside a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I want to run a directory/folder located on the root of server same place where other laravel file are located. but when I put url like www.example.com/mobile/functions.php its not working, in return laravel's route not found message received.

My Directory Structure is

1. -\Root

```
- app
- config
  - database
  - mobile
    > - db.php
    > - index.php
    > - +functions.php
  - *public
  - resources
  - route
  - storage
  - tests
  - vendor
```

I want to run that mobile folder as www.example.com/mobile.

Anyone Help me 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

place it in public folder or same folder with your index.php